# Unit Test for HashSet<T> with auto implenented property initializer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest, dotcover

I would like to write a unit test to check `HashSet` in C# MSTest to cover `ICollection` of my class, like this:

```
public ICollection<ObjectClass> Object { get; private set; } = new HashSet<ObjectClass>();
```

[image]

Does anybody know how to Assert this section of the code?

Edit1:
I didn't want to ignore or exclude auto-property initializers I am looking a way to test them

Comment: I would not test that it is a HashSet tough, as the class exposes an ICollection. I would only test that it is not null and empty when I create a new instance of the class (assuming that is a property of a non static, non abstract class and all that).

Comment: I think this shouldn't be tested at all

Comment: @Marco Indeed, it already has [tests](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Collections/tests/Generic/HashSet/HashSet.Generic.Tests.cs).

Comment: it's true but the coverage test shows this needs to be tested either.

Comment: You will test this when you write tests for the class where this collection is used. You don't need to write tests for this property separately.

Comment: What tool are you using to measure the test coverage?

Comment: @Rango ReSharper

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Arbitrary 100% coverage reports are nonsense. What does testing this achieve?

Comment: @Liam I don't know, I asked the community how to test.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno is right, the answer is don't.

Comment: @Liam then If I removed the HashSet in my code will be ok? I don't think so

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329430/exclude-auto-properties-from-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2015) and [this](https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206618825-DotCover-ignore-simple-Getters-and-Setters-in-Analysis)?

Comment: @Rango it's a solution when you want to exclude but I want to know if there is a way to tests or not.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad: it's a bug which came with auto implemented properties, you should not test. The latest version of dotCover should have fixed it. MSTest's Code Coverage analysis has the same bug

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a test that checks that the underlying implementation of `ShiftTemplateCalendar` is of a specific type.

You have to write tests that *use* this property (e.g. add / remove an element) or at least check that this property is never null (even right after constructing the object that holds the collection).

In one of your comments you asked, if it would be okay to remove this property from your class. As we can see in your screenshot, there are 3 of 3 tests passing this property. So if there are at least 3 tests using this property, why shouldn't that line be tested?

Seems to be a bug in your coverage tool.