# In .Net Core 3.1 how to exclude auto properties from the code coverage?

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage

This question is the modern reincarnation of [Exclude auto properties from Code Coverage in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329430/exclude-auto-properties-from-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2015) I am only interested in VS 2019 and .Net Core 3.1.

My current CodeCoverage.runsettings file contains the following section:

```
<Attributes>
  <Exclude>
    <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
    <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
    <Attribute>^System\.CodeDom\.Compiler\.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
    <Attribute>^System\.Runtime\.CompilerServices\.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
    <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.CodeAnalysis\.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
  </Exclude>
</Attributes>
```

The point is that the auto properties are attributed with `CompilerGenerated` attribute. However, this approach is wrong, because the `async` methods are also transformed by the compiler into methods with this same attribute. So using this approach we lose coverage on the `async` methods. Not good.

So, is there a way in VS code coverage to skip coverage on auto properties like we can do in OpenCover or DotCover?

Answer (score 2):

The following addition to my `.runsettings` file excluded auto props, but not manually coded properties or the async methods.

Under `<CodeCoverage><Functions><Exclude>`

> ```
>      <Function>.*get_.*</Function>
>      <Function>.*set_.*</Function>
> ```

Not perfect, but...